# Stick wafer sticks to mudcake

Tags: cake, cookies, decorating

How can I stick chocolate wafer sticks like this:

[image]

on a mudcake to get this result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coat the outside of the cake with a moderate layer of icing to bind the stick cookies.  This is analogous to the mortar behind facade bricks in building a wall.

You could also put a drop of icing underneath the bottom, but that probably is not necessary.

Update:  I just noticed in the photo you can actually see some of the icing between the cookies, showing this is exactly how the show case cake in the photo was done.

Comment: Just to clarify do you mean royal icing or butter cream?

Comment: Either would work.  Royal icing will stand up for longer.  Buttercream (depending on which variety you use) should work fine for at least the first showing, assuming you keep the cake reasonably cool.  Of course, buttercream will taste far better.

Comment: Thanks, would icing work on fondant too? I just finished fondanting the cake with green

Comment: I imagine you could spread icing as a layer *on top* of the fondant, just to bind the cookies, yes.  To be neater, you might spackle each cookie, and stick it on, then, instead of trying to spread a binding layer on top of the fondant.  This is probably a job for royal icing if you don't have a better icing already made.